# Custom Navigation Title in iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to implement a custom Navigation Title on an iOS app.

The StoryBoard looks like this:

[image]

The place that I want to have the custom Navigation Title is the last view ( the message view ), and because I use an image and text this means that I need to have custom width and height. By needing this if I do in `viewDidLoad`:

```
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: 150, height: 88)
titleView = UIView(frame: rect)
......
titleView?.addSubview(imageView)
......
titleView?.addSubview(label)
navigationItem.titleView = titleView
```

The height of the title is blocked to 44pt.

But how I managed to do it is adding the subViews to the navigation bar:

```
var navigationBar: MessagesNavigationBar? {
    guard let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar as? MessagesNavigationBar else {
        return nil
    }
    return navigationBar
}
```

And in `viewDidLoad`

```
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: 150, height: 88)
titleView = UIView(frame: rect)
......
titleView?.addSubview(imageView)
......
titleView?.addSubview(label)
navigationBar?.addSubview(titleView!)
```

But the problem is that I have to remove the subviews when I leave the view, otherwise whatever I add there will be present in the table view as well.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if navigationBar != nil {
        titleView?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Which kinda makes me feel that I'm not doing the right thing and I find difficult to add a fade out animation to those subViews when I leave the conversation. (i.e. native messages app on iOS).

So what is the right way of creating a custom Title Navigation Bar in iOS 12?

Scenes

[image]

Comment: “By needing this I can't use something like in viewDidLoad” why can’t you? That’s the normal and right thing to do...

Comment: Sorry, I was ambiguous, and I edited the question. So, if I use `navigationItem.titleView = titleView` I cannot change the height of the `titleView` which is by default 44.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Creating your custom `titleView` and assigning it to `navigationItem.titleView` is what you want. On older systems (pre iOS 11) you just might need to call `sizeToFit()` on the `titleView`.

This way you can create this titleView

Swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let imageView = UIImageView()
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
        imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20)
    ])
    imageView.backgroundColor = .red
    
    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    titleLabel.text = "Custom title"
    
    let hStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [imageView, titleLabel])
    hStack.spacing = 5
    hStack.alignment = .center
    
    navigationItem.titleView = hStack
}
```

Obj-C

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        [imageView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:20],
        [imageView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:20]
    ]];
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    titleLabel.text = @"Custom title";

    UIStackView *hStack = [[UIStackView alloc] initWithArrangedSubviews:@[imageView, titleLabel]];
    hStack.spacing = 5;
    hStack.alignment = UIStackViewAlignmentCenter;
    
    self.navigationItem.titleView = hStack;
}
```

[image: title view]

You might also need to have the right set of autolayout constraints or use `UIStackView`.

Comment: `sizeToFit()` is not working since iOS 11 as far as I read on other stackoverflow answers, I tried to use that first time as the default height is 44 and I didn't found a way to change it.

Comment: Than probably your constraints don't define size of the titleView.

Comment: I don't have any constrains as is just a Navigation Controller -> Table Controller -> View Controller + Navigation Bar. I added to the question a print with the Scenes as well. By the way, the `sizeToFit` method is not even called.

Comment: The `titleView` inside need constraints...btw. you were right since iOS 11 `sizeToFit()` is not needed

Comment: I've edited the original answer so it is a bit clearer

Comment: I'm getting something, https://i.imgur.com/9NVwUmk.png. I put `hStack.axis = .vertical` as well to have them in rows, I assume from this stage I can make them as big as I want? Is first time when I'm using stackViews (first app as well).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183988/discussion-between-olejnjak-and-sebastian-corneliu-virlan).

Comment: Great idea using a StackView! Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to do this within Objective-C?

Comment: Sure, I updated the answer so it also states Obj-C.

Answer (score 3):

These lines have no effect on the size of a title view:

```
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: 150, height: 88)
titleView = UIView(frame: rect)
```

Instead (or in addition) give your title view a width constraint and a height constraint. That is how the runtime knows what size you want.